# Why list variable store only one value?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I created a loop with extract data from web page and store the data in list variable but this variable always contain one value, why is that ?

```
WebAutomation.ExtractData.ExtractSingleValue BrowserInstance: Browser ExtractionParameters: {[$'''a.postlink[href*=\"download\"]''', $'''Href''', $''''''] } TimeoutInSeconds: 60 ExtractedData=> NewOutput
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have selected the Single Value option in the Live Web Helper. Your Robin code starts with:

```
WebAutomation.ExtractData.ExtractSingleValue
```

List extraction would look like the below:

```
WebAutomation.ExtractData.ExtractList
```

You can change the type of extraction in the advance settings of the action.

[image]

Comment: I extract single value (href) from the page but I want to store it in List variable but the variable always has only one item.